# How can I elminated warnings in Gatling ReponseProcessor

Tags: scala, gatling

I have some code in my scenario such as

```
.check(status.is(200), jsonPath("$['resultData'][*]['@contentType']").findAll.saveAs("resultData")) 
.check(status.is(500), jsonPath("$['processingError']").find.saveAs("processingError"))
```

but I keep getting the following

```
10:36:51.946 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'GetAllThings' failed: status.find.is(200), but actually found 500
10:36:52.344 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'GetAllThings' failed: status.find.is(500), but actually found 200
```

Is there some way I can construct my checks so that I don't get these messages, because I am already handling both cases?

I have tried several variations, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are these two seperate checks on two different execs?  Have you tried printing the response code.  The failure indicates you were looking for response code of 200 but the response is coming as 500 - which is a valid failure.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this does what I want (mostly)

```
.check(
  status.in(Seq(200, 400, 500)),
  jsonPath("$['resultData'][*]").findAll.optional.saveAs("resultData"),
  jsonPath("$['processingError']").optional.saveAs("processingError")
)
```

I say mostly because while it solves one problem, it creates another. Basically the 400 and 500 errors are captured, but now they are not marked as KO, so the statistics don't count them. I tried explicitly returning

```
sesson.markAsFailed
```

in my exec(), but that does not work, probably because once you are out of the check, the failure does not count (pun intended).